# Looking for the title &/or author of an urban fantasy book series

Tags: story-identification, vampire, urban-fantasy

I read the first book in an urban fantasy series in the early 2000's not long after it was published. I've wanted to finish it for a while but I cant find the book don't remember the title or author, please help.

The book takes place in the modern day. The protagonist is a female vampire who is the only known vampire in the book's world who is also pyrokinetic. Her maker is an ancient Egyptian vampire. She has to team up with a human hunter who also has powers and was born in Roman times.

The main antagonists of the book are Nephilim, but I don't believe they were fallen Angels. The Nephilim in the story belong to different clans, each clan has power over a different classical element: earth, air, water, etc. They are extremely powerful but haven't been seen in the story for hundreds or thousands of years.

The story is at least a trilogy, but it could be a series.

If this seems familiar to anyone any info would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Nephilim are not fallen angels.  They are the offspring of angels (or other lesser divine beings) and human women.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Weird. Sounds a bit like some characters from Chelsea Quinn Yarbro's Olivia books, but only the characters' origins match.

Comment: Thank you for the response mkennedy. I looked up Chelsea Yarbos's books, and while some of them are definitely similar she isn't the author of the books I'm looking for.